# What is the **tidyverse** method for splitting a df by multiple columns?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to split a dataframe by multiple columns so that I can see the `summary()` output for each subset of the data.

Here's a way to do that using `split()` from `base`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Loading tidyverse: ggplot2
#> Loading tidyverse: tibble
#> Loading tidyverse: tidyr
#> Loading tidyverse: readr
#> Loading tidyverse: purrr
#> Loading tidyverse: dplyr
#> Conflicts with tidy packages ----------------------------------------------
#> filter(): dplyr, stats
#> lag():    dplyr, stats

mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  mutate(GRP_A = sample(LETTERS[1:2], n(), replace = TRUE),
         GRP_B = sample(c(1:2), n(), replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  split(list(.$GRP_A, .$GRP_B)) %>% 
  map(summary)
#> $A.1
#>       mpg             cyl           disp          GRP_A          
#>  Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.0   Min.   :108.0   Length:10         
#>  1st Qu.:14.97   1st Qu.:4.5   1st Qu.:151.9   Class :character  
#>  Median :18.50   Median :7.0   Median :259.3   Mode  :character  
#>  Mean   :17.61   Mean   :6.4   Mean   :283.4                     
#>  3rd Qu.:20.85   3rd Qu.:8.0   3rd Qu.:430.0                     
#>  Max.   :24.40   Max.   :8.0   Max.   :472.0                     
#>      GRP_B  
#>  Min.   :1  
#>  1st Qu.:1  
#>  Median :1  
#>  Mean   :1  
#>  3rd Qu.:1  
#>  Max.   :1  
#> 
#> $B.1
#>       mpg             cyl           disp          GRP_A          
#>  Min.   :15.00   Min.   :4.0   Min.   : 75.7   Length:5          
#>  1st Qu.:21.00   1st Qu.:4.0   1st Qu.: 78.7   Class :character  
#>  Median :21.50   Median :4.0   Median :120.1   Mode  :character  
#>  Mean   :24.06   Mean   :5.2   Mean   :147.1                     
#>  3rd Qu.:30.40   3rd Qu.:6.0   3rd Qu.:160.0                     
#>  Max.   :32.40   Max.   :8.0   Max.   :301.0                     
#>      GRP_B  
#>  Min.   :1  
#>  1st Qu.:1  
#>  Median :1  
#>  Mean   :1  
#>  3rd Qu.:1  
#>  Max.   :1  
#> 
#> $A.2
#>       mpg             cyl             disp          GRP_A          
#>  Min.   :15.20   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 95.1   Length:9          
#>  1st Qu.:16.40   1st Qu.:6.000   1st Qu.:160.0   Class :character  
#>  Median :18.10   Median :8.000   Median :275.8   Mode  :character  
#>  Mean   :19.84   Mean   :6.667   Mean   :234.0                     
#>  3rd Qu.:21.00   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:275.8                     
#>  Max.   :30.40   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :360.0                     
#>      GRP_B  
#>  Min.   :2  
#>  1st Qu.:2  
#>  Median :2  
#>  Mean   :2  
#>  3rd Qu.:2  
#>  Max.   :2  
#> 
#> $B.2
#>       mpg             cyl         disp          GRP_A          
#>  Min.   :13.30   Min.   :4   Min.   : 71.1   Length:8          
#>  1st Qu.:14.97   1st Qu.:4   1st Qu.:125.3   Class :character  
#>  Median :20.55   Median :6   Median :201.5   Mode  :character  
#>  Mean   :20.99   Mean   :6   Mean   :213.5                     
#>  3rd Qu.:23.93   3rd Qu.:8   3rd Qu.:315.5                     
#>  Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8   Max.   :360.0                     
#>      GRP_B  
#>  Min.   :2  
#>  1st Qu.:2  
#>  Median :2  
#>  Mean   :2  
#>  3rd Qu.:2  
#>  Max.   :2
```

How can I achieve this same result using a `tidyverse` verb? My initial thought was to use `purrr::by_slice()`, but apparently that has been deprecated.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use split? Are you looking to definitely split or would group_by work as well?

Comment: I try to avoid mixing r "dialects", so the `.$GRP_A` isn't to my taste. `group_by` is no good - it returns a grouped data.frame, but `summary()` doesn't recognize the groups.

Comment: Now that I've typed it out, my preference for the `tidyverse` "dialect" may be unnecessarily picky... but if I had the choice, I'd go with the `tidyverse` verb over `split` any day, so I just thought I'd see if there's something I overlooked.

Comment: You could use `do(s=summary(.))`

Comment: @HubertL that's a nice way to do it! Would you like to submit an answer or should I?

Comment: @Tiernan Go ahead, thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dplyr 0.8.0 has introduced the verb that you were looking for: `group_split()`

From the documentation:

> `group_split`() works like `base::split()` but
>
> - it uses the grouping structure from group_by() and therefore is    subject to the data mask
> - it does not name the elements of the list based on the grouping as    this typically loses information and is confusing.
>
> `group_keys()` explains the grouping structure, by returning a data
>   frame that has one row per group and one column per grouping variable.

For your example:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(1:3) %>% 
  mutate(GRP_A = sample(LETTERS[1:2], n(), replace = TRUE),
         GRP_B = sample(c(1:2), n(), replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_split(GRP_A, GRP_B) %>% 
  map(summary)
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** this answer is now outdated. See @MartijnVanAttekum's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57239963/5170276) above.

---

The "tidy" solution seems to be a combination of "mutate + list-cols + purrr" [according to Hadley](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1118#issuecomment-237930445).

```r
library(tidyverse) 
library(magrittr) 

# group, nest, create a new col leveraging purrr::map()
mt_summary <- 
    mtcars %>% 
    select(1:3) %>% 
    mutate(GRP_A = sample(LETTERS[1:2],  n(), replace = TRUE), 
           GRP_B = sample(c(1:2), n(), replace = TRUE)) %>% 
    group_by(GRP_A, GRP_B) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(SUMMARY = map(data, .f = summary))

# check the structure
mt_summary
#> # A tibble: 4 Ã— 4
#>   GRP_A GRP_B              data     SUMMARY
#>   <chr> <int>            <list>      <list>
#> 1     A     1 <tibble [11 Ã— 3]> <S3: table>
#> 2     B     2  <tibble [9 Ã— 3]> <S3: table>
#> 3     A     2  <tibble [7 Ã— 3]> <S3: table>
#> 4     B     1  <tibble [5 Ã— 3]> <S3: table>

# extract the summaries
extract2(mt_summary, "SUMMARY") %>% 
    set_names(paste0(extract2(mt_summary, "GRP_A"), 
                     extract2(mt_summary, "GRP_B")))
#> $A1
#>       mpg             cyl             disp      
#>  Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 75.7  
#>  1st Qu.:15.25   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:120.9  
#>  Median :19.20   Median :6.000   Median :167.6  
#>  Mean   :20.43   Mean   :6.182   Mean   :229.0  
#>  3rd Qu.:25.85   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:309.5  
#>  Max.   :30.40   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :460.0  
#> 
#> $B2
#>       mpg             cyl             disp      
#>  Min.   :15.20   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 78.7  
#>  1st Qu.:17.80   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:120.3  
#>  Median :19.20   Median :6.000   Median :167.6  
#>  Mean   :20.84   Mean   :6.222   Mean   :225.9  
#>  3rd Qu.:21.50   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:351.0  
#>  Max.   :32.40   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :400.0  
#> 
#> $A2
#>       mpg             cyl             disp      
#>  Min.   :15.20   Min.   :4.000   Min.   : 71.1  
#>  1st Qu.:18.90   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:114.5  
#>  Median :21.40   Median :6.000   Median :145.0  
#>  Mean   :21.79   Mean   :5.429   Mean   :176.0  
#>  3rd Qu.:22.10   3rd Qu.:6.000   3rd Qu.:241.5  
#>  Max.   :33.90   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :304.0  
#> 
#> $B1
#>       mpg             cyl           disp      
#>  Min.   :10.40   Min.   :4.0   Min.   :140.8  
#>  1st Qu.:13.30   1st Qu.:8.0   1st Qu.:275.8  
#>  Median :14.30   Median :8.0   Median :350.0  
#>  Mean   :15.62   Mean   :7.2   Mean   :319.7  
#>  3rd Qu.:17.30   3rd Qu.:8.0   3rd Qu.:360.0  
#>  Max.   :22.80   Max.   :8.0   Max.   :472.0
```

Comment: I read [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1118) that `do` was "going away", although it's not clear exactly what that means.

Comment: Hmm... I'll file an issue on the `purrr` github repo and see if I can get one of the dev's to weigh in on this. Thanks for the heads up @aosmith!

Comment: Seems that others have advocated for `by_slice` to be saved: https://github.com/hadley/purrr/issues/270

Comment: You could use dmap right after the grouping. You get a data frame, not a list and you lose the row names

Comment: @FlorianGD I didn't get the result I was looking for by substituting `dmap(.f = summary)` for the `do` line... and I also got a warning that `dmap` will soon be deprecated.

Comment: Issue posted to the dplyr repo: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2518

Comment: Question posted to the [manipulatr mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/manipulatr): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/manipulatr/EMARFJfSvwY/BjXiY1kVDgAJ